# How to use the two of values "auto" and "contain" at the same time in "background-size" property?

Tags: html, css

I'm designing my own image viewer and I'm getting a problem while displaying the image as a background in div tag.

I have 2 pictures, the dimession of the first picture is larger than the second's.

I want to show the image in the center of the div. And the problem is:

The first picture requires the property: `background-size: contain;`, but the second picture requires `background-size: auto;`.

I'd also tried to use the `auto` value for the first picture, and the result is: the background size is larger than the div size (`d3` class).

Same to the second's, if I use the `contain` value, the background size will become bigger to fit the div size (which I don't want).

My question: Is there anyway to let the background size uses the `contain` value if the background image has a big dimession, and otherwise?

Thank you!

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #000;
}

div {
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.d1 {
  background-image: url('https://preview.ibb.co/gXcQpU/tutay.jpg');
  background-size: contain;
}

.d2 {
  background-image: url('https://image.ibb.co/ggcEip/red.png');
  background-size: contain;
}

.d3 {
  background-image: url('https://preview.ibb.co/gXcQpU/tutay.jpg');
  background-size: auto;
}

.d4 {
  background-image: url('https://image.ibb.co/ggcEip/red.png');
  background-size: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="d1"></div>

<div class="d2"></div>

<div class="d3"></div>

<div class="d4"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of background images use inline images and flex:

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #000;
}

div.imageviewer {
   display:flex;
   flex-wrap:wrap;
}

div[class^=d] {
   flex: 0 1 auto;
   max-width:400px;
   height: 200px;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
   overflow: hidden;
}

img {
max-width:100%;
height:auto;
max-height:200px;
display:block;
}

div[class^=d] {
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  /* background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px; */
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

/* .d1 {
  background-image: url('https://preview.ibb.co/gXcQpU/tutay.jpg');
  background-size: contain;
}

.d2 {
  background-image: url('https://image.ibb.co/ggcEip/red.png');
  background-size: contain;
}

.d3 {
  background-image: url('https://preview.ibb.co/gXcQpU/tutay.jpg');
  background-size: auto;
}

.d4 {
  background-image: url('https://image.ibb.co/ggcEip/red.png');
  background-size: auto;
} */
```

```html
<div class="imageviewer">

<div class="d1"><img src="https://preview.ibb.co/gXcQpU/tutay.jpg"></div>

<div class="d2"><img src="https://image.ibb.co/ggcEip/red.png"></div>

<div class="d3"><img src="https://preview.ibb.co/gXcQpU/tutay.jpg"></div>

<div class="d4"><img src="https://image.ibb.co/ggcEip/red.png"></div>

</div><!-- end image viewer -->
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use 'img' and/or 'picture' HTML5 elements instead.

Read more here: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/responsive/picture-element/